# Ошибка в opencv-python:AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

у меня пишет ошибку:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    # cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том что ваш файл называется `cv2.py` поэтому он импортирует самого себя и возникает ошибка, это можно понять из этой строки.

> most likely due to a circular import

что переводится как:

> скорее всего из-за кругового импорта

Чтобы исправить проблему переименуйте свой файл

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Maxim2010 тогда примите мой ответ(галочка слева от ответа)